# Issue with WSO2 StratosLive

Tags: wso2, wso2-stratos

I've faced an issue deploying a sample Spring application to WSO2 StratosLive, as reported at https://wso2.org/jira/browse/STRATOS-2118.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

We will have a look. But in the meantime can you try this out with standalone server. which in this case WSO2 Application Server. Even though WSO2 AS support Spring jars in the runtime, it does not support spring classLoading. To give more context the WSO2 servers are based on an OSGi runtime. Typically each OSGi bundle has its own classLoader and hence own classLoader.

From the first glance it seems to be like classLoading issue related to above behaviour.

HTH

Comment: I have successfully deployed to WSO2 AS 5 without issues, but not to WSO2 StratosLive. The code is published at [GitHub](http://github.com/fribeiro1/springsample-wso2stratoslive).